# 2011 MacBook Pro monitor as a 2nd display for Windows 7 (Display port) laptop

Tags: macbook-pro, displayport

How can I use my 2011 MacBook Pro monitor as a 2nd display for my Windows 7 Lenovo Laptop (Display port)?

Answer (score 3):

iMac's support what is known as [Target Display Mode](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht3924#4). However, this is limited to iMac's only, Macbook Pro laptops do not support this.

Alternatively, you can use your Macbook Pro as a secondary monitor by using an app such as [Air Display](http://www.avatron.com/applications/air-display/).

Air Display is an app that will allow another shared desktop to display on it, over wifi.  However, if you are doing any critical photo, video or even games, you will find the lag to be very annoying.

Answer (score 2):

## ScreenRecycler - Share Displays

You can not use your MacBook Pro as a second monitor for your Windows computer without additional software. For Mac using a Windows computer, there is software such as [ScreenRecycler](http://www.screenrecycler.com/ScreenRecycler.html):

> Use your other computer as an additional display for your Mac.
>
> Recycle your old iMac, PowerBook or even Windows PC now.

I am not aware of the reverse piece of software to go from Windows to Mac.

[image: ScreenRecycler]

### Synergy - Combine Computers

Alternatively, [Synergy](http://synergy-foss.org) is an open source solution that [lets you combine multiple computers](http://lifehacker.com/254648/how-to-control-multiple-computers-with-a-single-keyboard-and-mouse) into one. It will let you use both computers from a single keyboard and mouse.

[image: Synergy]

Comment: Downvoting because Synergy does NOT support use of another machine as a second display (https://github.com/symless/synergy/wiki/User-FAQ), as asked for in the question.  The screenshot of Synergy showing three displays may also suggest that it can handle multiple displays, but it only does the keyboard and mouse.

Comment: Screen Recycler in this answer is appropriate. Synergy is mentioned because it may provide the questioner with an approach they had not considered before.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it (not supported for Win8--good for them!), but [Maxivista](http://www.maxivista.com/mac-as-a-second-monitor.htm) seems to be a solution for using a MacBook/iMac as a monitor for your PC. From the [demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i2AE8ySovoQ), it seems you still need Screen Recycler on your Mac (~$29), (other reqs: VNC and both computers need to be on the same network).